# Web-based online discussion tool (forum) that supports post from email

Tags: email, forum

I'm looking for a web-based tool (ideally self-hosted) that:

Must have:

- Online threaded discussions (similar to Facebook comments)
- Integration with email, so people can follow topics and join the discussion from email (similar to most helpdesk tools)

Nice to have:

- Is a WordPress plugin
- Offers iPhone and Android apps
- Integration with Facebook groups so people can join the discussion from a Facebook group (not sure if this is even technically possible)

Answer (score 1):

How about EasyDiscuss https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easydiscuss/
for Joomla which has threads and email integration along with posting to  Facebook & Twitter.